# What can be done to make java 6 compatible with Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My project in built in Java 6, I need to integrate it with Kafka but I have been getting the compatibility issue. I don't want to upgrade my java version. Is there any way to make Kafka(kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1) work with Java 6?

Following is the Error that I have been getting:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Answer (score 3):

Java 1.6 Support was dropped years ago (in Apache Kafka Release 0.9)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2316